# Command line file rename with date and time

Tags: command-line, files, rename

I want to do a weather cam web page I have the command line to take the photo from the webcam then upload it via FTP but I want to do a backup of the photo with time and date as the file name so currently it would be `201410162011.jpg` I have tried tried to google for the info but with no luck.

Answer (score 7):

If your photo is named `file.jpg` and you want to back it up to a file named after the date, then run:

```
cp file.jpg "$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M').jpg"
```

If the back-up files go in a different directory:

```
cp file.jpg "/path/to/backups/$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M').jpg"
```

If, instead of backing it up, you wanted to *rename* the file, then use `mv` in place of `cp`:

```
mv file.jpg "$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M').jpg"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need a one-liner then this should work:

```
cp photo.jpg "/path/to/backup/folder/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M).jpg"
```

Otherwise I'd recommend storing the date in a variable then calling the cp command.

```
date=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)
cp "$source" "/path/${date}.jpg"
```

Comment: Thanks to both responders Six and John1024 this is what i wanted and worked like a charm